# Converting dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm to MySQL TIMESTAMP

Tags: python, mysql, sql, csv, excel-formula

I'm using python to take data from a csv and putting it into a MySQL database.
The csv has timestamps in the format dd-mm-YYYY HH:mm. I'd like to put the value of these cells into the database as TIMESTAMP (so I'd want YYYY-mm-dd HH:mm:00).

I can't find a SQL CONVERT command or something I could do with Excel formulas (or the python csv module for that matter) to convert the whole lot automatically without losing any data. Can you help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use python's [strptime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.strptime) for the parsing and [strftime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.strftime) for the construction of the format that you need:

```
>>> import time
>>> s = '12-01-1980 12:15'
>>> time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M', time.strptime(s, '%d-%m-%Y %H:%M'))
'1980-01-12 12:15'
```

Comment: @Nicholas, thanks for accepting the answer :) a voteup will also be appreciated (if you haven't yet). Thanks!

Comment: sorry about that, there you go!